# Call closure, that's in a collection, with the owner of the collection

Tags: compiler-errors, rust, borrow-checker

Consider the following code:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
type KeyCode = char;
type CmdType = Fn(&mut E);

struct E {
    key_map: HashMap<KeyCode, Box<CmdType>>,
}

impl E {
    fn map_key(&mut self, key: KeyCode, function: Box<CmdType>) {
        self.key_map.insert(key, function);
    }
    fn quit(&mut self) { println!("quitting"); /* ... */ }
}

fn main() {
    let mut e = E { key_map: HashMap::new() };
    e.map_key('q', Box::new(|e: &mut E| e.quit()));

    match e.key_map.get(&'q') {
        Some(f) => f(&mut e),
        None => {}
    }
}
```

which [doesn't compile](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=51262278ab48c1635d4a&version=stable) because I'm trying to pass `e` to `f`:

> cannot borrow `e` as mutable because `e.key_map` is also borrowed as immutable

But when the borrow of `e.key_map` ends I will no longer have access to `f`. So how exactly can I call the closure that's inside  the map?

Answer (score 1):

> So how exactly can I call the closure that's inside the map?

This depends on what behaviour is appropriate.

As you've worked out, calling `f(&mut e)` is impossible if `f` is borrowed from `e`. The solutions are

- Don't pass `&mut e` to the function. This is impractical if `E` is not under your control.
- stop `f` from borrowing from `e`. Since `CmdType` is not `Clone`able, one cannot simply copy it out. However, you should be able to temporarily remove `f` from the map:

  ```
  let removed = e.key_map.remove(&'q');
  if let Some(f) = removed {
      f(&mut e);
      e.key_map.insert('q', f);
  }
  ```

Comment: The closures must have access to `e` somehow. For now I just stored `key_map` outside of `E`, and kept a reference to it in `E`. It's impractical too but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to make `E` *not* own the map, if that's appropriate, and instead separate that functionality to another struct. Something like this:

```
struct K {
    key_map: HashMap<KeyCode, Box<CmdType>>,
}

impl K {
    fn map_key(&mut self, key: KeyCode, function: Box<CmdType>) {
        self.key_map.insert(key, function);
    }
}

struct E;

impl E {
    fn quit(&mut self) { println!("quitting"); /* ... */ }
}

fn main() {
    let mut k = K { key_map: HashMap::new() };
    k.map_key('q', Box::new(|e: &mut E| e.quit()));

    let mut e = E;
    match k.key_map.get(&'q') {
        Some(f) => f(&mut e),
        None => {}
    }
}
```

`E` might also have a reference to the `K` instance if needed.